# how to append a <option> value to dropdown using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a project in which i have to append a dropdown options to selection list .I have tried to append options but am not getting them in dropdown. while i am getting values in debugging

```
$("#p_combination").empty();
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var dish_name = response[i]['dish_name'];
    var pincode = response[i]['pincode'];

    $("#p_combination").append("<option value='" + dish_name + "'>" + dish_name + "</option>");
    document.getElementById('pincode').value = pincode;
}
```

```html
<select name="p_combination[]" id="p_combination" multiple>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML and a more complete sample of your JS code - including how you retrieve the `response` value. There's no reason this shouldn't work when used correctly, as you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/c0ywLn6b/

Comment: `document.getElementById('pincode').value = pincode || "";` seems you have issues here. try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#p_combination").empty();
//supposing that your response object is something like :
var response=[{'dish_name':'name1','pincode':1},{'dish_name':'name2','pincode':2},{'dish_name':'name3','pincode':3}];
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
 $("#p_combination").append("<option value='" + response[i]['dish_name'] + "'>" +response[i]['dish_name'] + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="p_combination[]" id="p_combination" multiple>
    <option value="0">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i am still not getting the result

Comment: why not? Run this code, it is working.. i think you have some error somewhere else in your script. check your response variable in the console `console.log(response)`  maybe it is an empty variable.

Comment: am getting response in [object object ] form..wile debuging...but dont knw why <option> not getting attached

Comment: I think that the error is in your php script, please post you php code.

Comment: i sent the code to your email id  amani.info.app@gmail.com... sorry to bother you...i got it from your home page

Comment: it would be better if you add it to your question too so everybody else will be able to help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.append()` method in jQuery as in the following example.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
     var newOptionValue = $('option').length;
     $('select').append('<option value="' + newOptionValue + '">Option ' + newOptionValue + '</option>');
    });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="p_combination[]" id="p_combination" multiple>
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Append Option</button>
```